Reading data from kafka and write to a hadoop/hbase/hive/spark stack batch procceing
I have a tech stack consisting of Hadoop as a distributed storage of raw data, HBase as a NoSQL database that runs on top of Hadoop and HDFS, Hive as an RDBMS data warehouse on top of Hive for applying structure(tables) on an unstructured data, Spark as an in-memory batch processing and execution engine on Hive, and Spark SQL for running queries.
There may be upsert operations while I am reading messages from Kafka.
How would I better write read messages and data from Kafka with this stack?
It means in which layer(hdfs, hbase, hive) should I Insert the input message to have a more updated batch processing on the Spark with consideration of the ACID principle in all layers and I/O performance?

In my opinion, you should insert the data from Kafka to Hbase. HBase is NoSQL and has very fast read/write which you could leverage for high throughput Kafka Streams. HBase can handle upsert as well very efficiently.
I am ruling out HDFS as it not suitable for upsert and Hive for it is not meant for OLTP type queries and upsert.
So, you can ingest the data into HBase first. Then you can use Apache Spark for processing the data in HBase. Spark can work with HBase through HBase-Spark connector. After processing the data, you can then move the result into Hive for further analysis or querying with Spark SQL.
One caution, while HBase does provide some level of ACID compliance, it is not fully ACID compliant like traditional RDBMSs. It provides strong consistency guarantees only at the row level.
